# Combine OS partion with data partition on NAS4Free/FreeNAS

Tags: freebsd, partitioning, freenas

I recently built a NAS4Free (formerly FreeNAS) machine using a 256MB (yes, MB) USB drive for the OS.  When I did the original install, I had the bright idea of making the OS partition just big enough for the OS and a then creating a second partition using the remainder of the drive to store stuff pertaining to the OS.  I never really found a use for the data partition and I ended up running out of space on the OS partition, so now I'd like to combine the partitions into a single partition.

Is this something that is possible to do while everything is up and running?  If it comes down to it, I can take down the machine and do a fresh install of the OS using the entire space of the USB drive, but I'd like to use this as an opportunity to better familiarize myself with FreeBSD/UNIX type systems.

If this is possible, will it interfere with the NAS4Free things?  The data partition shows up in the web interface under the disks section.  If I end up manually changing the partitions, I'd be concerned with NAS4Free getting confused by the missing partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do anything else *make a backup!*

Use [gpart](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gpart&sektion=8&n=1)'s <kbd>delete</kbd> command to remove the unused partition. Then use gpart's <kbd>resize</kbd> command to expand the partition containing your filesystem

If you used the UFS filesystem, you can then use [growfs](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=growfs&sektion=8)(8) to expand it. On FreeBSD versions <10.0, the filesystem must be unmounted before growing it. The easiest way to do that is by booting from a live-CD.

Read the manual pages carefully before proceeding.